# Pointers and structs

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define HASH_SIZE 100

// prototype
int hash(char *word);

// counter
int counter;

// node
typedef struct
{
    char *word;
    node *next;
} node;

// hash table
node *hashtable[HASH_SIZE];

bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open the dictionary
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // set all values in the hash table to null
    for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // set the counter to 0
    counter = 0;

    // iterate through the words in the dictionary
    while (!feof(dict))
    {
        // get word into a string
        char gotcha[LENGTH];
        fscanf(dict, "%s", gotcha);

        // declare a node and allocate memory
        node n;
        n.word = malloc( strlen(gotcha)*sizeof(char) );

        // save the word into the node
        strcpy(n.word, gotcha);

        // hash the word, baby!
        int hash_value = hash(n.word);

        // start saving addresses to the hashtable
        n.next = hashtable[hash_value];
        hashtable[hash_value] = &n;

        //test
        int len = strlen(n.word);
        printf("%s\n", n.word);
        printf("%i\n", len);

        // that's one more!
        counter++;
    }


    fclose(dict);

    return true;
}
```

I am receiving the following two errors on these two lines of code:

```
    n.next = hashtable[hash_value];
    hashtable[hash_value] = &n;
```

dictionary.c:89:16: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
dictionary.c:90:31: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
How do I save pointer values in these two places? I am new to this, so please bear that in mind. :)

Comment: you are missing half the code needed to figure out what is going on.

Comment: how is the hashtable defined?

Comment: Okay, I added code to answer these two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your structure, the type node is not yet defined. Change it to use the structure tag:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Comment: Or, better, declare the struct before defining it:
    `typedef struct node node;
    struct node {
        char* word;
        node* next;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *word;
    node *next;
} node;
```

is a syntax error. The `node *next;` occurs before the end of the typedef that creates `node` as a type. If your compiler for some reason accepted this, it probably thinks there are 2 different types called "node" now, which explains why one of them isn't compaible with the other. You should give up on that typedef silliness (structs generally shouldn't be typedef'ed) and just use

```
struct node
{
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: There is no basis for the assertion that structs shouldn't be typedefed, and there are millions of lines of C code using typedefed structs.

Comment: [Linux kernel CodingStyle](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) chapter 5 is a well-thought out argument on the topic. It basically says "don't typedef"

Comment: I wouldn't call that well thought out at all. `"vps_t a; in the source, what does it mean? In contrast, if it says struct virtual_container *a; you can actually tell what "a" is."` is a ridiculous and dishonest comparison of apples and oranges. `struct vps a` is no clearer that `vps_t a`. `virtual_container *a` is no less clear than `struct virtual_container *a`. Competent professionals don't abide by dishonest arguments.

Comment: Then just take this question with the messed-up `node` definition as evidence. It wouldn't have happened if someone wasn't trying to be too clever with typedef. I've seen many other instances of the same clever brokenness , motivated by a desire to strip away as many instances of the `struct` keyword as possible, an unreasonable obsession for anyone but especially unreasonable for a beginner. I say let them learn how structs work in the absence of typedefs first. It's less complex.

Comment: No, it's not evidence. Competent professional programmers typedef structs; in C++, that's how they all are. I said there is no basis for the assertion and none has been given, not by Linus and not by you ... it's just an ideological stance. My last word.

Answer (score 0):

Define typedef names of structs before defining the structs. This allows mutually referring structs without concern for order and doesn't require inconsistent definitions, sometimes with the struct keyword and sometimes without it. Note that in C++ you can do away with the typedef line entirely:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
    char* word;
    node* next;
};
```